# Running SQL Jobs in parallel

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have two scheduled SQL Jobs configured in SQL Agent.

Job 1 starts at every day 3 AM

Job 2 starts at every day 4 AM

Usually Job 1 will completed in 30 to 40 mins, but in future there will be more process will be added to Job 1, so eventually it will take more than one hour to complete. My question if the Job 1 runs more than one hour i.e.past 4 AM, what will happen to Job 2 will it run in parallel or Job 2 waits until the Job 1 completes?
Any suggestions will be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have scheduled job 2 to run at 4 am, it wont wait for job 1, it will run at that time.   you have to understand that these are two different jobs :)

Comment: If you have dependencies you can add this to your last step in Job 1 and disable the schedule in job2 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Job 2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Job 2 will execute in parallel without any doubt**. So if there is any dependency than you need to take of those.